# GAE: Does execution continue after hitting "Exceeded soft private memory limit"?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue, memory-limit

One of my GAE task-queue requests exceeded the soft memory limit (log below). My understanding of the soft memory limit is that it lets the request complete and then after it finishes, it shuts down the instance.

However, from the logs, it looks like when I hit the soft memory limit, execution stops. I see no  more logging code after the memory limit message and I've inspected my state and it does not look like the request is completing. I'm not sure if it matters, but this request is executing in within a deferred library TaskQueue.

So, if a TaskQueue hits a soft private memory limit, does execution continue until the request completes or does it immediately halt? Is it possible that only logging code is no longer recorded?

Log:

```
2012-04-11 23:45:13.203
Exceeded soft private memory limit with 145.848 MB after servicing 3 requests total
W 2012-04-11 23:45:13.203
After handling this request, the process that handled this request was found to be using too much memory and was terminated. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may have a memory leak in your application.
```

[image: Log Screenshot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What happens here is that handler **at the end** checks the memory status, if it is above the limit it will log an error and will shutdown the instance.
Since the task has completed successfully (you can see it terminates will status 200) it will not retry it.

When **during** handler execution the memory status is way above the memory limit, the handler will shutdown the instance and will return error 500, at this case the task will retry.

Comment: @speedplane there is a limit to logging per request, but you should see the last logs in the logs viewer

Comment: +1, but are you sure about the instance being shut down immediately? I had my backend instance exceeded its soft memory limit for several times, and from what I observed, the instance could still serve requests before being abruptly shut down after a period of time. (minutes, at least)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Look at the log I just posted. It seems to crash without printing any logging code at all.

Comment: Even if it completes, it is definitely not printing logging code. Is this a bug?

Comment: Or perhaps logging code does not get printed when memory is way too high and there is a status 500?

Answer (score -1):

From my experience: if your instance hits soft memory hit, your request still would be finished, but the response status would be 500.

Comment: Here the response status is 200.

Comment: it was 200 before, but i think now is 500, or there are two kinds of memory hits, the "Exceeded soft private memory limit" alway give me 500

Comment: The response status is up to the app, unless it's terminated before it could finish (because, for instance, it hit the hard memory limit or the time limit).

Comment: if you check the screenshot above, the response is a 500.